# LINQ which return Dictionary<string, List<Item>> from collection C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

LINQ expert how to convert this to linq.

```
Public Class Item    
{

   Public string Name {get;set;}  

   Public string Value {get;set;}

   Public bool IsDis {get;set;}

}
```

I have collection which is like this

```
{ 
  Name ="ABC", Value="x", IsDis= true

  Name ="ABC", Value="y", IsDis=false

  Name ="ABC1", Value="1",  IsDis false

  Name ="ABC1", Value="2", IsDis= true        
}
```

As Name property has list of value. so I have to write LINQ query like this which return

```
  Dictionary <string, List<Item>> = collection??????
```

Comment: GroupBy(), ToDictionary() and ToList()? (with some educate guessing because you didn't say what dictionary key is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupBy` by `Name` and then collect it into a `Dictionary`.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Item>> resultSet = collection
                               .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: If name is the key, the name should be distinct, but  Name ="ABC" and  Name ="ABC1" keys are repeated. In that case, the above logic will not hold.